# Extract left-upper triangular data from a square matrix-form list

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, data-structures, trees

Hopefully, this question is not too basic or obscure. I'd like an idea on how to extract this

```
{{1}, {5, 2}, {9, 6, 3}, {13, 10, 7, 4}}
```

from

```
m = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}}
```

Naturally, the square matrix can grow in size, but I will need upper-left (reverse-triangular) information from it (including reverse-diagonal itself).

I thought this can be done by fist permuting (rotating) the matrix and then extracting upper or lower triangular, but not sure if Mathematica has the tools to follow on this approach or if there is a more natural/easier way.

Thanks in advance for a constructive idea or a reference to it.

Comment: @rhermans . Thank you for suggestions and links. I will take the time to follow up on references and answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two functions to consider: [`Diagonal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Diagonal.html) and [`Reverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reverse.html)

Your data:

```
m = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}}
```

---

### Solution

```
Reverse@Table[
  Reverse@Diagonal[Reverse /@ m, k], {k, 0, Length[m] - 1}]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {5, 2}, {9, 6, 3}, {13, 10, 7, 4}}
> ```

Function:

```
lut[m_] := 
 Reverse@Table[
   Reverse@Diagonal[Reverse /@ m, k], {k, 0, Length[m] - 1}]
```

or as pointed by J. M.

```
 lut[m_] := Table[Diagonal[Reverse[m], k], {k, 1 - Length[m], 0}]
```

---

### Extended example

```
Column@Array[MatrixForm@lut@Partition[Range[# #], #] &, 7]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Documentation

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The same idea, but only one reverse: `Reverse@m~Diagonal~# & /@ Range[1 - Length@m, 0]`

Comment: At that point, I'd have used an explicit `Table[]`, tho: `Table[Diagonal[Reverse[m], k], {k, 1 - Length[m], 0}]`

Answer (score 6):

Just to show a less elegant way :)

```
f[m_] := Apply[m[[##]] &, Table[{i - j + 1, j}, {i, Length@m}, {j, i}], {2}]
f@m
(*{{1}, {5, 2}, {9, 6, 3}, {13, 10, 7, 4}}*)
```

Comment: @"belisaurius has settled" I copied and pasted the definition twice but am getting an error message *Part specification ... is longer than the depth of the object*.

Comment: I get the same error as @JackLaVigne! I used `Extract` instead of `Part` for this type of solution to avoid exactly that problem, I think.

Comment: Ah! Fixed it: `m[[##]] & @@@ # & /@ Table[{i - j + 1, j}, {i, Length@m}, {j, i}]`. Now, have you ever before used a construction like `f @@@ #& /@ list`?

Comment: @march, at that point I use an explicit `Apply[]` rather than appeal to a baroque construction. ;)

Comment: @J.M. Baroque is definitely the correct description. :)

Comment: @march Thanks! surely a copy-paste-mess error

Answer (score 6):

```
m = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};

MapThread[m[[##]] &, {Reverse@Range@#, Range@#}] & /@ Range@Length@m
```

> {{1}, {5, 2}, {9, 6, 3}, {13, 10, 7, 4}}

Answer (score 5):

Here's a different version, much more verbose.

```
m = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};

DeleteCases[#, 0]&@*Reverse /@ Transpose @ UpperTriangularize @ MapThread[RotateRight[#1, #2] &, {m, Range[0, Length@m - 1]}]
```

Here's another one, slightly less verbose:

```
MapIndexed[Reverse@#1[[;; First@#2]] &, Transpose@MapThread[RotateRight[#1, #2] &, {m, Range[0, Length@m - 1]}]]
```

Even less verbose:

```
Extract[m, #] & /@ Table[{n - j + 1, j}, {n, 1, Length@m}, {j, 1, n}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
upperOffTriag[m_] := With[
 {i = Table[Table[{n, k + 1 - n}, {n, k, 1, -1}], {k, 1, First@Dimensions[m]}]},
 Map[Part[m, Sequence @@ #] &, i, {2}]
]

upperOffTriag[m]
```

> {{1}, {5, 2}, {9, 6, 3}, {13, 10, 7, 4}}

Answer (score 2):

We want to extract the index of the upper left triangular position using the positions:

```
{1,1}
{2,1}
{1,2}
{3,1}
{2,2}
{1,3}
  ⋮
```

The following function using `Table` uses the algorithm so that the row increments and then decrements as the column increments (not sure the words make sense but look at the algorithm below).

```
lut1[m_] := Table[
  Table[
   m[[j - i + 1, i]],
   {i, 1, j}
  ],
  {j, Length@m}
  ]
```

So now with

```
m = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}}
```

`lut1[m]` produces

```
{{1}, {5, 2}, {9, 6, 3}, {13, 10, 7, 4}}
```

**Timing**

Let's take a quick look at timing for a large matrix.

```
bigM = Table[i + j, {i, 1000}, {j, 1000}];
```

Applying ***rherman's*** first solution

```
lut[m_] := 
 Reverse@Table[
   Reverse@Diagonal[Reverse /@ m, k], {k, 0, Length[m] - 1}]

lut[bigM]; // Timing
(* {4.00923, Null} *)
```

The solution in this answer:

```
lut1[bigM]; // Timing
(* {0.577204, Null} *)
```

is a bit faster.

But if you are looking for blinding speed, nothing beats ***March's*** second answer:

```
lut2[m_] := 
 MapIndexed[Reverse@#1[[;; First@#2]] &, 
  Transpose@
   MapThread[RotateRight[#1, #2] &, {m, Range[0, Length@m - 1]}]]

lut2[bigM]; // Timing
(* {0.0156001, Null} *)
```

### Update

Since submitting the answer two more answers have appeared.

***Suba Thomas***

```
upperOffTriag[m_] := With[
 {i = Table[Table[{n, k + 1 - n}, {n, k, 1, -1}], {k, 1, First@Dimensions[m]}]},
 Map[Part[m, Sequence @@ #] &, i, {2}]
]

upperOffTriag[bigM]; // Timing
(* {1.46641, Null} *)
```

***Eldo***

```
lutEldo[m_] := 
 MapThread[m[[##]] &, {Reverse@Range@#, Range@#}] & /@ Range@Length@m

lutEldo[bigM]; // Timing
(* {0.592804, Null} *)
```

Comment: I find it surprising that my second solution is faster than my third. Interesting.

Comment: @march I get it is about 25 times slower ~ 0.4 compared to 0.0156. I don't know if this is related to the selection of 1000 x 1000 for the size.

Comment: Yeah, me too. I just think it's weird. And I checked that the construction of the list of coordinates is essentially instantaneous. Since (I think) `Map` takes advantage of vectorized operations, there must be a lot of overhead for each call to `Extract`.

Answer (score 2):

Very verbose but I was trying to find a different way :)

```
Reverse[Flatten@
    Pick[m, Normal@
      SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; Abs[j + i] == # -> 1}, {4, 4}], 1] & /@
   Range[2, 5], 2]
```